# Load Textfile via Drag and Drop on Textarea

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, filereader

I'm trying to add the ability to drag and drop a textfile into a textarea. However, I'm getting the following error.

> > Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

[image]

Which according to the error line 19 is

```
reader.readAsText(input.files[0],"UTF-8");
```

I see it's saying `parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'`; However, can someone please explain why is this error showing and what can I do to fix this error?

```js
function dropfile(input) {
  var reader = new FileReader();  
  reader.onload = function(e) {            
    notepad.value = e.target.result;
  }        
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0],"UTF-8");
};
notepad.ondrop = function(e) {
  this.value = "";
  e.preventDefault();
  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  dropfile(file);
};
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#notepad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: calc(100vw - 2em);
  resize: none;
}
#notepad:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="notepad" placeholder="drag and drop your .txt file"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the file to `dropfile` function.

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
dropfile(file);
```

in `dropfile` function you are consuming it wrong.

```
reader.readAsText(input.files[0],"UTF-8");
```

you should change the line to

```
reader.readAsText(input,"UTF-8");
```

Try the below snippet.

```js
function dropfile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    notepad.value = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
}

notepad.ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  dropfile(file);
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#notepad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: calc(100vw - 2em);
  resize: none;
}

#notepad:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea
  id="notepad"
  placeholder="drag and drop your .txt file"
></textarea>
```

Comment: Got twice dropEvt call (Edge) and had to add e.stopPropagation(); or e.cancelBubble = true; ("IE only") to stop second; there was also eventPhase 2 -> 3 property changed between calls on event. And no luck in FF - looks like not supported by cursor(?)